# Postgresql 11 slow vacuum

Tags: postgresql

I have a local install of postgresql 11 on my Windows 10 desktop (for my machine learning PhD). The data folder is 76gb (~15 tables, the largest has 100m rows). The  database sits on a Samsung 970 EVO Plus and when inserting new rows, I can see write speed reaching >500mb/s in task manager. However, when I run `vacuum` or `analyze`, task manager reports disk I/O of 3-5mb/s and it takes hours (before I manually terminated the process). What am I doing wrong here?

Here are some changes I've made to `postgresql.conf`.

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# RESOURCE USAGE (except WAL)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Memory -

shared_buffers = 512MB          # min 128kB
                    # (change requires restart)
#huge_pages = try           # on, off, or try
                    # (change requires restart)
temp_buffers = 1024MB           # min 800kB
#max_prepared_transactions = 0      # zero disables the feature
                    # (change requires restart)
# Caution: it is not advisable to set max_prepared_transactions nonzero unless
# you actively intend to use prepared transactions.
work_mem = 128MB                # min 64kB
maintenance_work_mem = 512MB        # min 1MB
autovacuum_work_mem = -1        # min 1MB, or -1 to use maintenance_work_mem
#max_stack_depth = 2MB          # min 100kB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = windows

# - Asynchronous Behavior -

#effective_io_concurrency = 0       # 1-1000; 0 disables prefetching
max_worker_processes = 8        # (change requires restart)
#max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 2   # taken from max_parallel_workers
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4 # taken from max_parallel_workers
#parallel_leader_participation = on
max_parallel_workers = 8
```

Comment: What are the values for `vacuum_cost_delay` and `vacuum_cost_limit`?

Comment: Both `vacuum_cost_delay` and `vacuum_cost_limit` were commented out (default). Ok this seems to have fixed it, I've backed up the database, dropped it, then restored from backup. It seems to `vacuum analyze` fine now. But  I guess this is masking the fact that I must have not used/vacuumed properly before.